# Remove items from associative array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I have an associative array in my JS which I want to feed my Select.

These are the standard hours available that will refresh my availablehours (when page loads);

```
var standardhours = {
  "09" : '9AM',
  "10" : '10AM',
  "11" : '11AM',
  "12" : 'Noon',
  "13" : '1PM',
  "14" : '2PM',
  "15" : '3PM',
  "16" : '4PM',
  "17" : '5PM',
  "18" : '6PM',
  "19" : '7PM'
};
```

These the available hours that I want to feed my Select.

```
var availablehours = {
    "09" : '9AM',
    "10" : '10AM',
    "11" : '11AM',
    "12" : 'Noon',
    "13" : '1PM',
    "14" : '2PM',
    "15" : '3PM',
    "16" : '4PM',
    "17" : '5PM',
    "18" : '6PM',
    "19" : '7PM'
};
```

This is my dynamic variable that changes based on database changes. These are the hours taken by someone already.

```
takenHours = {"09", "18"};
```

I want to remove the takenHours from the availablehours associative array. Not sure how. The thought process I have feels very manual and simplistic.

Comment: That is an invalid object.

Comment: Should `takenHours` be an array like this? `takenHours = ["09", "18"];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you should be able to achieve this kind of mutation of `availablehours` via the `delete` operator, as shown:

```js
var availablehours = {
  "09": '9AM',
  "10": '10AM',
  "11": '11AM',
  "12": 'Noon',
  "13": '1PM',
  "14": '2PM',
  "15": '3PM',
  "16": '4PM',
  "17": '5PM',
  "18": '6PM',
  "19": '7PM'
};
console.log(availablehours);

var takenHours = ["09", "18"];

// Iterate through the hours to be removed
for (var takenHour of takenHours) {

  // For each hour key, use the delete operator to remove 
  // the key/value pair from availablehours completlty
  delete availablehours[takenHour]
}

// availablehours will no longer contain "09" or "18" key/value pairs
console.log(availablehours);
```